# LOG4J working fine on eclipse localhost but not on Linux Server

Tags: java, maven, log4j, httpserver

Having problem with Log4j and don't have much experience with it.

I'm running a Linux server and deploying a java HTTPServer to it. When running the HTTP server as a local host with Eclipse, the log4j only shows INFO, which is what I (think I) have specified in the log4j file. But on the server it will display DEBUG messages as well, completely bombarding the terminal.

I would like it to work on the server as it does on eclipse, only showing INFO messages. It seems as though some configuration is available for eclipse that does not work on the server.

Most likely it's me who have failed in some way making it so that the server does not read the properties file. But would appreciate help in solving this matter.

Thanks in advance :)

Log4J properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
```

Comment: i had a same issue here.Have you found the solution?

Comment: any solution then please share

Comment: Was quite sometime since I last worked on it, but can't seem to remember me finding a solution to it.